# Filtering by the value of an internal list using MongoAlchemy

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoalchemy

I'm building a Flask app with Flask-MongoAlchemy, and I'm having trouble putting together a query.

I have the following document structure, for a 'Group' document:

```
{'name': 'some_name',
 'participants': [
     {'participant_id': 12345}
     {'participant_id': 98765}
     ]
}
```

I'm trying to write the method `Participant.groups()`, which makes a call to the database to return all instances of Group where there is a `participant_id` which matches `self.id`.

I'm reading over the MongoAlchemy docs, though, and am finding very little on how to query based on an internal list.

After looking over the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701427/mongodb-filtering-the-content-of-an-internal-array-in-a-resultset), I tried

```
def groups(self):
    return Group.query.filter(Group.participants.participant_id == self.id)
```

But perhaps unsurprisingly, it throws an error when it tries to evaluate `participants.participant_id`.

Any insight? I've seen examples using the regular MongoDB syntax, but am at a loss at how to achieve this using MongoAlchemy.

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Great success!

Dropping down to PyMongo syntax seemed like the way to go in this case:

```
def groups(self):
    return Group.query.filter(
        {'participants': {'$elemMatch': {'participant_id': self.id}}}).all()
```