# MongoDB: find and findOne with nested array filtering

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This little task turned out to be harder than I thought.

Consider the following very simple Posts collection. Suppose I want to display all the posts, coupled with only the comments that were not deleted.

I.E. filter out the deleted comments from the comments array.

Since I have 100s of deleted comments per post, is there a way to do this server side?

The collection:

```
{
  "author": {},
  "message": "This is post1",
  "comments": [
    {
      "message": "Im number 1!!!",
      "state": {
        "deleted": false
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "YOU MOTHERF****R",
      "state": {
        "deleted": true
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "tHIS IS GREAT!",
      "state": {
        "deleted": false
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "I can type better than you guys",
      "state": {
        "deleted": false
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "author": {},
  "message": "This is post 2",
  "comments": [
    {
      "message": "This is bulls**t",
      "state": {
        "deleted": true
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "YOU MOTHERF****R",
      "state": {
        "deleted": true
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "I hate u!",
      "state": {
        "deleted": true
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "I wanna have your children",
      "state": {
        "deleted": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll **TL;DR** since this turned out to be a hell of a ride. I've tried `$elemMatch`, I've tried `$redact` (also with $$CURRENT and $$ROOT), I've tried `$map`, I've tried the aggregation framework, I've tried `$project`.

You can read all about it here: https://www.devsbedevin.net/mongodb-find-findone-with-nested-array-filtering-finally/

### TL;DR

The solution seems to be to use the aggregation framework to filter the array and override the comments property with the results. This is simpler than it sounds:

```
db.getCollection('posts').aggregate(
    {$match: {"author.id": authorId}},
    {$addFields : {"comments":{$filter:{ // We override the existing field!
        input: "$comments",
        as: "comment",
        cond: {$eq: ["$$comment.state.deleted", false]}
    }}}}
);
```

The result:

```
{
  "author": {},
  "message": "This is post1",
  "comments": [
    {
      "message": "Im number 1!!!",
      "state": {
        "deleted": false
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "tHIS IS GREAT!",
      "state": {
        "deleted": false
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "I can type better than you guys",
      "state": {
        "deleted": false
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "author": {},
  "message": "This is post 2",
  "comments": [
    {
      "message": "I wanna have your children",
      "state": {
        "deleted": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Guess MongoDB is just [not intended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701503/3002584) for this kind of filtering :)

Comment: @OfirD - in hindsight I admit I didn't understand how to use MongoDB properly. 

I should have created a separate document for the comments and embed the non deleted ones into the messages document. If you need to filter embedded arrays in MondgoDB, it means you do not understand MogoDB.

I do like the solution though :)

Comment: curious - by "if you need to filter embedded arrays in MondgoDB, it means you do not understand MogoDB", do you have in mind anything more than what's described in the link I referred to? If you do, it would be great if you can elaborate (maybe in the post itself) or just share some article you recommend :)

Comment: @OfirD - sure. The official recommendation is to prefer [embedding data](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/embedded-mongodb) to either referencing it or (as I did) dumping everything in the same document and trying to server-side filter it.

Comment: @OfirD - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70124690/606351