# how to update the element of object which is in array and that array is in object. Mongoose and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update the object which is in array and that array in object. I am using mongoose I have 2 schemas SlotTracker and Slot. I am adding slot in array. as following.
this is my database.

```json
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60a39e210976153090842b46"
  },
  "bookings": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b8ac254006ed40604eac86"
      },
      "aDate": {
        "$date": "2021-06-12T00:00:00.197Z"
      },
      "aShift": "morning",
      "slotsAvailable": 3,
      "slotsBooked": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b8ac384006ed40604eac9d"
      },
      "aDate": {
        "$date": "2021-06-14T00:00:00.197Z"
      },
      "aShift": "morning",
      "slotsAvailable": 3,
      "slotsBooked": 0
    }
  ],
  "courtID": 2,
  "__v": 0
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60b7a9199f7c244f3c9053c4"
  },
  "bookings": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b8ac604006ed40604eacb5"
      },
      "aDate": {
        "$date": "2021-06-12T00:00:00.197Z"
      },
      "aShift": "morning",
      "slotsAvailable": 6,
      "slotsBooked": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b8ac6d4006ed40604eaccd"
      },
      "aDate": {
        "$date": "2021-06-13T00:00:00.197Z"
      },
      "aShift": "morning",
      "slotsAvailable": 6,
      "slotsBooked": 0
    }
  ],
  "courtID": 3,
  "__v": 0
}]
```

I am tring to change values of **slotsBooked** and **slotsAvailale** if they exist in booking array of that requested court. if it is not there in array of requested court then add new slot int array of that court.

### schemas

- SlotTracker :

```js
Schema({
courtId: {
        type: Number
    },
    bookings: {
        type: Array
    }
});
```

- Slot

```js
Schema({
    aDate: {
        type: Date
    },
    aShift: {
        type: String
    },
    slotsAvailable: {
        type: Number
    },
    slotsBooked: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

> I want to change the slotAvailable and slotBooked  if and only if that aDate and aShift matches with  provided aDate and aSlot

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation framework trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46323107/606351

Basically filter the array and then override what properties you want changed or added.

Comment: I tried but I was unable to write query for that. Thanks