# whereBetween doesn't work in laravel mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb

Hello I'm new in MongoDB laravel and I have the following error:

This is the object I want to query in Mongo.

[MongoDB Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osxsd.png)

I want to fetch timestamps that are greater than or equal to 2022/7/5 and less than or equal to 2022/7/6, according to my logic in Laravel with the Jenssegers/laravel-mongodb, would have this:

```
$tracks =  TrackFishing::where('boat_id', '3')
    ->whereBetween(
         'tracking.timestamp', array(
             Carbon::createFromDate(2022, 7, 5),
             Carbon::createFromDate(2022, 7, 6)
         ))
    ->first();
```

I want to get position 0 of the timestamp but this throws me empty, I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Did you check what `(string)Carbon::createFromDate(2022, 7, 5)` will return ? it returns (right now) `"2022-07-05 14:43:30"` so as you can see it depends on when you do the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved with a aggregate:

```
$cursor = Model::raw()->aggregate([
        ['$match' => [
                'tracking.timestamp' => [
                    '$gte' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $request->fecha_inicio)->startOfDay()),
                    '$lte' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $request->fecha_fin)->endOfDay())
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ]);
```

[this question helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701427/mongodb-filtering-the-content-of-an-internal-array-in-a-resultset)

thank you all for replying

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the hour, minute and second

```
$tracks =  TrackFishing::where('boat_id', '3')
    ->whereBetween(
         'tracking.timestamp', array(
             Carbon::createFromDate(2022, 7, 5)->startOfDay(),
             Carbon::createFromDate(2022, 7, 6)->endOfDay()
         ))
    ->first();
```

Comment: I tried it and so I get the two positions but because of the range I should only get the 0

Comment: @Monicagutierrez how did you get two positions with `first()` which returns only one result ? if you used another code, mind share that code in your question ?

Comment: because first() is for parent element but tracking.timestamp is a child

Comment: @Monicagutierrez what are you talking about ? please edit your question and expand the code to include the code related to what you are talking about.

Answer (score -1):

try with this one;

```
    'tracking.timestamp', [
        Carbon::createFromDate(2022, 7, 5),
        Carbon::createFromDate(2022, 7, 6)
    ]
```

Comment: Changing how you declare the array doesn't change the result. both syntax are equal and valid